# Running Word similarity Glove

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have tried to run Glove on my Ubuntu machine. It was Ok until it gave me the following error that complains about matlab :

```
./demo.sh: line 37: matlab: command not found
```

Can anybody help me how to set up matlab on my machine to run Glove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution-1:**
matlab command part is only the intrinsic test part of glove tool. 
You don't need to run that part of demo.sh to generate word vectors.

**Solution-2:**
Moreover, with new release of GloVe which is **version 1.2**, there is python code to do that. Matlab is not necessary, python will handle it.

demo.sh has an if elif code part which checks if there exists a matlab running on machine. If exists, it runs matlab, if not checks for octave. If octave exists, it runs octave. If octave doesnot exist it runs with python. demo.sh has following code, and matlab part is the last part of it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Makes programs, downloads sample data, trains a GloVe model, and then evaluates it.
# One optional argument can specify the language used for eval script: matlab, octave or [default] python

make
if [ ! -e text8 ]; then
  if hash wget 2>/dev/null; then
    wget http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip
  else
    curl -O http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip
  fi
  unzip text8.zip
  rm text8.zip
fi

CORPUS=text8
VOCAB_FILE=vocab.txt
COOCCURRENCE_FILE=cooccurrence.bin
COOCCURRENCE_SHUF_FILE=cooccurrence.shuf.bin
BUILDDIR=build
SAVE_FILE=vectors
VERBOSE=2
MEMORY=4.0
VOCAB_MIN_COUNT=5
VECTOR_SIZE=50
MAX_ITER=15
WINDOW_SIZE=15
BINARY=2
NUM_THREADS=8
X_MAX=10

$BUILDDIR/vocab_count -min-count $VOCAB_MIN_COUNT -verbose $VERBOSE < $CORPUS > $VOCAB_FILE
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
  then
  $BUILDDIR/cooccur -memory $MEMORY -vocab-file $VOCAB_FILE -verbose $VERBOSE -window-size $WINDOW_SIZE < $CORPUS > $COOCCURRENCE_FILE
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
  then
    $BUILDDIR/shuffle -memory $MEMORY -verbose $VERBOSE < $COOCCURRENCE_FILE > $COOCCURRENCE_SHUF_FILE
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
       $BUILDDIR/glove -save-file $SAVE_FILE -threads $NUM_THREADS -input-file $COOCCURRENCE_SHUF_FILE -x-max $X_MAX -iter $MAX_ITER -vector-size $VECTOR_SIZE -binary $BINARY -vocab-file $VOCAB_FILE -verbose $VERBOSE
       if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
       then
           **if [ "$1" = 'matlab' ]; then
               matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash < ./eval/matlab/read_and_evaluate.m 1>&2 
           elif [ "$1" = 'octave' ]; then
               octave < ./eval/octave/read_and_evaluate_octave.m 1>&2 
           else
               python eval/python/evaluate.py
           fi**
       fi
    fi
  fi
fi
```

**IN SHORT:**
New version of Glove which is Glove 1.2 solves your problem. Just run it.
matlab, octave or python, one of them is enough for running the script. If you have one of them, demo.sh will handle it.

Comment: How can we train our own corpus on Glove? Is it necessary to run demo.sh file.?

Comment: as far as I remember it is necessary but I used glove long time ago. sorry.